# Get Application Path to create a new File

Tags: java, eclipse, path

How can I get the Application path of a Project in a String variable LogPath. The LogPath is used later on to create a Log File of the Project. Am using Eclipse for coding.

Comment: What do you mean by Application path?

Comment: Application path is one where I run the Source Project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USE

```
String AbsolutePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

Explanation : `File(".")` represents the current directory and `getAbsoultePath()` returns absolute path to the current directory.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would use

```
String logPath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

.. for start.

Comment: Actually I am passing this value to a table in database. when I use this method, the value is taken to the database.

Comment: Ok, congratulations, but it is totally irrelevant :) You can do whatever you want with that string. For instance, you can even tweet it.

Comment: still i dont get the table field log path when I give the path in this way.  propertyInterface.addProperty("LogPath",logPath); this is how I did it. But when I hard code the value of log path, it works.

Answer (score 1):

This call: `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` gives you the current working directory of your application. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Which Language are you using?

Java:

```
File directory = new File (".");
System.out.println ("Current directory's canonical path: " +     directory.getCanonicalPath());
System.out.println ("Current directory's absolute  path: " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
```